# Loading xyz-tiles using QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, xyz-tiles, qgis-modeler

A background map can be imported into QGIS by e.g. adding a new xyz-tile connection. Example of a working connection (satellite data from Google): [http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

Is there an option to automate this process in the graphical modeler in QGIS i.e. is it possible to load a background map by assigning the url in the modeler?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but you can use pyqgis to add xyz sources to the browser, see: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py

Comment: Is it possible to make such a script visible in the graphical modeller?